# WebGL objects not rendering properly when moving camera

Tags: javascript, webgl2

I am trying to render a lot of objects. It worked fine on 1 object, just not on multiple. It is causing some of the vertices not to be rendered when looking around to the right of the camera:
[image: Back]

But when I look to the left of the camera, it works:
[image: Front]

But in reality, it's in quadrants:

```
("[]" = working, "||" = not working)

[][][][]||||||||
[][][][]||||||||
[][][][]||||||||
[][][][]||||||||
||||||||||||||||
||||||||||||||||
||||||||||||||||
||||||||||||||||
```

and if I try to move my camera (Let's say down 3 left 1)

```
("[]" = working, "||" = not working)

[][][]||||||||||
[][][]||||||||||
[][][]||||||||||
[][][]||||||||||
[][][]||||||||||
[][][]||||||||||
[][][]||||||||||
||||||||||||||||
```

I have tried changing the "`gl.cullFace(gl.BACK);`" function to `gl.cullFace(gl.FRONT);`, but that doesn't help, neither does `gl.cullFace(gl.FRONT_AND_BACK);`, but that causes the objects to disappear.

I use `gl.drawElements();` to draw the elements, and, for the position buffer, I just add every vertex (X, Y, Z) by its position.

```js
var x = 3;
var y = 4;
var z = 5;
var i = 0;
var verticies = Array.from([
// verticies
], e => {
    var g = i % 3;
    if (g == 0) {
        e += x * (e * 2); // So you can just have x = 1, and x = 2 without clipping
    } else if (g == 1) {
        e += y * (e * 2);
    } else if (g == 2) {
        e += z * (e * 2);
    }
    i += 1;
    return e;
})
```

Frame:

```js
function frame() {
    // gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height); // NOT NEEDED (I believe)
    gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    // gl.cullFace(gl.BACK); // NOT NEEDED
    gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);
    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl.clearDepth(1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.useProgram(program);
    return;
}
```

Here's my `Mat4` and `Camera` classes:

Mat4:

```js
class Mat4 {
    #mat = [
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
    ];
    get Matrix() {
        return this.#mat;
    }
    set(p, n) {
        n = parseFloat(n);
        p = parseInt(p);
        if (isNaN(n)) {
            console.error(`N must be a number.`);
            return;
        }
        if (isNaN(p)) {
            console.error(`P must be a number.`);
            return;
        }
        if (p > 15 || p < 0) {
            console.error(`P must be inbetween 0 and 15.`);
            return;
        }
        this.#mat[p] = n;
    }
    translate(pos = new Vec3(0, 0, 0)) {
        if (!(pos instanceof Vec3)) {
            console.error(`Pos is not a Vec3.`);
            return;
        }
        this.#mat[12] = this.#mat[0] * pos.x + this.#mat[4] * pos.y + this.#mat[8] * pos.z + this.#mat[12];
        this.#mat[13] = this.#mat[1] * pos.x + this.#mat[5] * pos.y + this.#mat[9] * pos.z + this.#mat[13];
        this.#mat[14] = this.#mat[2] * pos.x + this.#mat[6] * pos.y + this.#mat[10] * pos.z + this.#mat[14];
        this.#mat[15] = this.#mat[3] * pos.x + this.#mat[7] * pos.y + this.#mat[11] * pos.z + this.#mat[15];
        return;
    }
    rotateX(degree = 0) {
        degree = parseInt(degree);
        if (isNaN(degree)) {
            console.error(`Degree is not a number.`);
            return;
        }
        degree = degree * (Math.PI / 180);
        var s = Math.sin(degree),
            c = Math.cos(degree),
            a10 = this.#mat[4],
            a11 = this.#mat[5],
            a12 = this.#mat[6],
            a13 = this.#mat[7],
            a20 = this.#mat[8],
            a21 = this.#mat[9],
            a22 = this.#mat[10],
            a23 = this.#mat[11];
        this.#mat[4] = a10 * c + a20 * s;
        this.#mat[5] = a11 * c + a21 * s;
        this.#mat[6] = a12 * c + a22 * s;
        this.#mat[7] = a13 * c + a23 * s;
        this.#mat[8] = a20 * c - a10 * s;
        this.#mat[9] = a21 * c - a11 * s;
        this.#mat[10] = a22 * c - a12 * s;
        this.#mat[11] = a23 * c - a13 * s;
        return;
    }
    rotateY(degree = 0) {
        degree = parseInt(degree);
        if (isNaN(degree)) {
            console.error(`Degree is not a number.`);
            return;
        }
        degree = degree * (Math.PI / 180);
        var s = Math.sin(degree),
            c = Math.cos(degree),
            a00 = this.#mat[0],
            a01 = this.#mat[1],
            a02 = this.#mat[2],
            a03 = this.#mat[3],
            a20 = this.#mat[8],
            a21 = this.#mat[9],
            a22 = this.#mat[10],
            a23 = this.#mat[11];
        this.#mat[0] = a00 * c - a20 * s;
        this.#mat[1] = a01 * c - a21 * s;
        this.#mat[2] = a02 * c - a22 * s;
        this.#mat[3] = a03 * c - a23 * s;
        this.#mat[8] = a00 * s + a20 * c;
        this.#mat[9] = a01 * s + a21 * c;
        this.#mat[10] = a02 * s + a22 * c;
        this.#mat[11] = a03 * s + a23 * c;
        return;
    }
    rotateZ(degree = 0) {
        degree = parseInt(degree);
        if (isNaN(degree)) {
            console.error(`Degree is not a number.`);
            return;
        }
        degree = degree * (Math.PI / 180);
        var s = Math.sin(degree),
            c = Math.cos(degree),
            a00 = this.#mat[0],
            a01 = this.#mat[1],
            a02 = this.#mat[2],
            a03 = this.#mat[3],
            a10 = this.#mat[4],
            a11 = this.#mat[5],
            a12 = this.#mat[6],
            a13 = this.#mat[7];
        this.#mat[0] = a00 * c + a10 * s;
        this.#mat[1] = a01 * c + a11 * s;
        this.#mat[2] = a02 * c + a12 * s;
        this.#mat[3] = a03 * c + a13 * s;
        this.#mat[4] = a10 * c - a00 * s;
        this.#mat[5] = a11 * c - a01 * s;
        this.#mat[6] = a12 * c - a02 * s;
        this.#mat[7] = a13 * c - a03 * s;
        return;
    }
    scale(scale = new Vec3(1, 1, 1)) {
        if (!(scale instanceof Vec3)) {
            console.error(`Scale is not a Vec3.`);
            return;
        }
        this.#mat[0] *= scale.x;
        this.#mat[1] *= scale.x;
        this.#mat[2] *= scale.x;
        this.#mat[3] *= scale.x;
        this.#mat[4] *= scale.y;
        this.#mat[5] *= scale.y;
        this.#mat[6] *= scale.y;
        this.#mat[7] *= scale.y;
        this.#mat[8] *= scale.z;
        this.#mat[9] *= scale.z;
        this.#mat[10] *= scale.z;
        this.#mat[11] *= scale.z;
        return;
    }
    mul(matrix = new Mat4()) {
        if (!(matrix instanceof Mat4)) {
            console.error(`Matrix is not a Mat4.`);
            return;
        }
        this.#mat[0] *= matrix.Matrix[0];
        this.#mat[1] *= matrix.Matrix[1];
        this.#mat[2] *= matrix.Matrix[2];
        this.#mat[3] *= matrix.Matrix[3];
        this.#mat[4] *= matrix.Matrix[4];
        this.#mat[5] *= matrix.Matrix[5];
        this.#mat[6] *= matrix.Matrix[6];
        this.#mat[7] *= matrix.Matrix[7];
        this.#mat[8] *= matrix.Matrix[8];
        this.#mat[9] *= matrix.Matrix[9];
        this.#mat[10] *= matrix.Matrix[10];
        this.#mat[11] *= matrix.Matrix[11];
        this.#mat[12] *= matrix.Matrix[12];
        this.#mat[13] *= matrix.Matrix[13];
        this.#mat[14] *= matrix.Matrix[14];
        this.#mat[15] *= matrix.Matrix[15];
        return;
    }
    div(matrix = new Mat4()) {
        if (!(matrix instanceof Mat4)) {
            console.error(`Matrix is not a Mat4.`);
            return;
        }
        this.#mat[0] /= matrix.Matrix[0];
        this.#mat[1] /= matrix.Matrix[1];
        this.#mat[2] /= matrix.Matrix[2];
        this.#mat[3] /= matrix.Matrix[3];
        this.#mat[4] /= matrix.Matrix[4];
        this.#mat[5] /= matrix.Matrix[5];
        this.#mat[6] /= matrix.Matrix[6];
        this.#mat[7] /= matrix.Matrix[7];
        this.#mat[8] /= matrix.Matrix[8];
        this.#mat[9] /= matrix.Matrix[9];
        this.#mat[10] /= matrix.Matrix[10];
        this.#mat[11] /= matrix.Matrix[11];
        this.#mat[12] /= matrix.Matrix[12];
        this.#mat[13] /= matrix.Matrix[13];
        this.#mat[14] /= matrix.Matrix[14];
        this.#mat[15] /= matrix.Matrix[15];
        return;
    }
    sub(matrix = new Mat4()) {
        if (!(matrix instanceof Mat4)) {
            console.error(`Matrix is not a Mat4.`);
            return;
        }
        this.#mat[0] -= matrix.Matrix[0];
        this.#mat[1] -= matrix.Matrix[1];
        this.#mat[2] -= matrix.Matrix[2];
        this.#mat[3] -= matrix.Matrix[3];
        this.#mat[4] -= matrix.Matrix[4];
        this.#mat[5] -= matrix.Matrix[5];
        this.#mat[6] -= matrix.Matrix[6];
        this.#mat[7] -= matrix.Matrix[7];
        this.#mat[8] -= matrix.Matrix[8];
        this.#mat[9] -= matrix.Matrix[9];
        this.#mat[10] -= matrix.Matrix[10];
        this.#mat[11] -= matrix.Matrix[11];
        this.#mat[12] -= matrix.Matrix[12];
        this.#mat[13] -= matrix.Matrix[13];
        this.#mat[14] -= matrix.Matrix[14];
        this.#mat[15] -= matrix.Matrix[15];
        return;
    }
    add(matrix = new Mat4()) {
        if (!(matrix instanceof Mat4)) {
            console.error(`Matrix is not a Mat4.`);
            return;
        }
        this.#mat[0] += matrix.Matrix[0];
        this.#mat[1] += matrix.Matrix[1];
        this.#mat[2] += matrix.Matrix[2];
        this.#mat[3] += matrix.Matrix[3];
        this.#mat[4] += matrix.Matrix[4];
        this.#mat[5] += matrix.Matrix[5];
        this.#mat[6] += matrix.Matrix[6];
        this.#mat[7] += matrix.Matrix[7];
        this.#mat[8] += matrix.Matrix[8];
        this.#mat[9] += matrix.Matrix[9];
        this.#mat[10] += matrix.Matrix[10];
        this.#mat[11] += matrix.Matrix[11];
        this.#mat[12] += matrix.Matrix[12];
        this.#mat[13] += matrix.Matrix[13];
        this.#mat[14] += matrix.Matrix[14];
        this.#mat[15] += matrix.Matrix[15];
        return;
    }
    replace(matrix = new Mat4()) {
        if (!(matrix instanceof Mat4)) {
            console.error(`Matrix is not a Mat4.`);
            return;
        }
        this.#mat = matrix.Matrix;
        return;
    }
    invert() {
        var a00 = this.#mat[0], a01 = this.#mat[1], a02 = this.#mat[2], a03 = this.#mat[3],
            a10 = this.#mat[4], a11 = this.#mat[5], a12 = this.#mat[6], a13 = this.#mat[7],
            a20 = this.#mat[8], a21 = this.#mat[9], a22 = this.#mat[10], a23 = this.#mat[11],
            a30 = this.#mat[12], a31 = this.#mat[13], a32 = this.#mat[14], a33 = this.#mat[15],
            b00 = a00 * a11 - a01 * a10,
            b01 = a00 * a12 - a02 * a10,
            b02 = a00 * a13 - a03 * a10,
            b03 = a01 * a12 - a02 * a11,
            b04 = a01 * a13 - a03 * a11,
            b05 = a02 * a13 - a03 * a12,
            b06 = a20 * a31 - a21 * a30,
            b07 = a20 * a32 - a22 * a30,
            b08 = a20 * a33 - a23 * a30,
            b09 = a21 * a32 - a22 * a31,
            b10 = a21 * a33 - a23 * a31,
            b11 = a22 * a33 - a23 * a32,
            det = b00 * b11 - b01 * b10 + b02 * b09 + b03 * b08 - b04 * b07 + b05 * b06;
        if (!det) {
            console.error(`Unable to invert matrix.`);
            return;
        }
        det = 1.0 / det;
        this.#mat[0] = (a11 * b11 - a12 * b10 + a13 * b09) * det;
        this.#mat[1] = (a02 * b10 - a01 * b11 - a03 * b09) * det;
        this.#mat[2] = (a31 * b05 - a32 * b04 + a33 * b03) * det;
        this.#mat[3] = (a22 * b04 - a21 * b05 - a23 * b03) * det;
        this.#mat[4] = (a12 * b08 - a10 * b11 - a13 * b07) * det;
        this.#mat[5] = (a00 * b11 - a02 * b08 + a03 * b07) * det;
        this.#mat[6] = (a32 * b02 - a30 * b05 - a33 * b01) * det;
        this.#mat[7] = (a20 * b05 - a22 * b02 + a23 * b01) * det;
        this.#mat[8] = (a10 * b10 - a11 * b08 + a13 * b06) * det;
        this.#mat[9] = (a01 * b08 - a00 * b10 - a03 * b06) * det;
        this.#mat[10] = (a30 * b04 - a31 * b02 + a33 * b00) * det;
        this.#mat[11] = (a21 * b02 - a20 * b04 - a23 * b00) * det;
        this.#mat[12] = (a11 * b07 - a10 * b09 - a12 * b06) * det;
        this.#mat[13] = (a00 * b09 - a01 * b07 + a02 * b06) * det;
        this.#mat[14] = (a31 * b01 - a30 * b03 - a32 * b00) * det;
        this.#mat[15] = (a20 * b03 - a21 * b01 + a22 * b00) * det;
        return;
    }
    reset() {
        this.#mat = [
            1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
        ];
        return;
    }
    constructor(pos = undefined) {
        if (pos instanceof Vec3) {
            this.translate(pos);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Camera:

```js
class Camera extends Mat4 {
    #x = 0.0;
    #y = 0.0;
    #z = 0.0;
    #cx = 0.0;
    #cy = 0.0;
    #cz = 0.0;
    #pcx = 0.0;
    #pcy = 0.0;
    #pcz = 0.0;
    #fov = 70.0;
    #near = 0.0;
    #far = 100.0;
    get cx() {
        return this.#cx;
    }
    get cy() {
        return this.#cy;
    }
    get x() {
        return this.#x;
    }
    get y() {
        return this.#y;
    }
    get z() {
        return this.#z;
    }
    camRotateX(deg) {
        this.#cx += deg;
        if (this.#cx < -90) {
            this.#cx = -90;
        } else if (this.#cx > 90) {
            this.#cx = 90;
        }
    }
    camRotateY(deg) {
        this.#cy += deg;
    }
    camRotateZ(deg) {
        this.#cz += deg;
    }
    camResetX(deg) {
        this.#pcx = this.#cx;
        this.#cx = deg;
    }
    camResetY(deg) {
        this.#pcy = this.#cy;
        this.#cy = deg;
    }
    camResetZ(deg) {
        this.#pcz = this.#cz;
        this.#cz = deg;
    }
    camSaveX() {
        this.#pcx = this.#cx;
    }
    camSaveY() {
        this.#pcy = this.#cy;
    }
    camSaveZ() {
        this.#pcz = this.#cz;
    }
    camRestoreX() {
        this.#cx = this.#pcx;
    }
    camRestoreY() {
        this.#cy = this.#pcy;
    }
    camRestoreZ() {
        this.#cz = this.#pcz;
    }
    camTranslate(pos = new Vec3(0, 0, 0)) {
        this.#x += pos.x;
        this.#y += pos.y;
        this.#z += pos.z;
    }
    get camMatrix() {
        this.calculate();
        return this.Matrix;
    }
    camReset() {
        var f = 1.0 / Math.tan(this.#fov / 2.0),
            nf = 1.0 / (this.#near - this.#far);
        this.set(0, f / (Minecraft.width / Minecraft.height));
        this.set(1, 0.0);
        this.set(2, 0.0);
        this.set(3, 0.0);
        this.set(4, 0.0);
        this.set(5, f);
        this.set(6, 0.0);
        this.set(7, 0.0);
        this.set(8, 0.0);
        this.set(9, 0.0);
        this.set(10, -(this.#far + this.#near) * nf);
        this.set(11, -1.0);
        this.set(12, 0.0);
        this.set(13, 0.0);
        this.set(14, -(2.0 * this.#far * this.#near) * nf);
        this.set(15, 0.0);
        return;
    }
    calculate() {
        this.camReset();
        this.rotateX(this.#cx);
        this.rotateY(this.#cy);
        this.rotateZ(this.#cz);
        this.translate(new Vec3(this.#x, this.#y - 1.72, this.#z));
        return;
    }
    constructor(pos = undefined, fov = 70.0, near = 0.0, far = 100.0) {
        super();
        fov = parseFloat(fov);
        near = parseFloat(near);
        far = parseFloat(far);
        if (isNaN(fov)) {
            console.warn(`Fov is NOT valid, setting to default.`);
            fov = 70.0;
        }
        if (isNaN(near)) {
            console.warn(`Near is NOT valid, setting to default.`);
            near = 0.0;
        }
        if (isNaN(far)) {
            console.warn(`Far is NOT valid, setting to default.`);
            far = 100.0;
        }
        fov = fov * (Math.PI / 180);
        var f = 1.0 / Math.tan(fov / 2.0),
            nf = 1.0 / (near - far);
        this.set(0, f / (Minecraft.width / Minecraft.height));
        this.set(1, 0.0);
        this.set(2, 0.0);
        this.set(3, 0.0);
        this.set(4, 0.0);
        this.set(5, f);
        this.set(6, 0.0);
        this.set(7, 0.0);
        this.set(8, 0.0);
        this.set(9, 0.0);
        this.set(10, -(far + near) * nf);
        this.set(11, -1.0);
        this.set(12, 0.0);
        this.set(13, 0.0);
        this.set(14, -(2.0 * far * near) * nf);
        this.set(15, 0.0);
        if (pos instanceof Vec3) {
            this.#x = pos.x;
            this.#y = pos.y;
            this.#z = pos.z;
        }
        this.#far = far;
        this.#near = near;
        this.#fov = fov;
        return;
    }
}
```

Here's my Vertex Shader:

```c
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec2 texcoord;
uniform mat4 model;
varying highp vec2 vtexcoord;
varying vec3 vnormal;
void main() {
    gl_Position = model * vec4(position, 1.0);
    vnormal = normal;
    vtexcoord = texcoord;
}
```

Here's my Fragment Shader:

```c
precision highp float;
varying vec3 vnormal;
varying highp vec2 vtexcoord;
uniform vec3 lightDir;
uniform sampler2D sampler;
void main(void) {
    vec3 norm = normalize(vnormal);
    float light = dot(lightDir, norm) * .5 + .5;
    vec4 tex = texture2D(sampler, vtexcoord);
    if (tex.a == 0.0) {
        discard;
    }
    gl_FragColor = vec4(tex.rgb * light, tex.a);
}
```

My texture buffer vertices:

```js
[
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0
]
```

Here's my normal vertices:

```js
[
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    -1.0, 0.0, 0.0
]
```

Here's my indices:

```js
[
    0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7,
    8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 11,
    12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15,
    16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19,
    20, 21, 22, 20, 22, 23
]
```

Here's my position vertices:

```js
[
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, -1.0
]
```

Comment: The camera code seems to be the important part of this, and (unless I'm being dense) it's missing from the question. Are you keeping everything within the frustum?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I updated the question to include my Mat4 and Camera class

Comment: Thanks. I meant the WebGL camera code, though. This feels like a shader issue.

Comment: I believe its how my model projection matrix calculates the position of the other verticies, ill go test that.

Comment: It seems that the projection matrix is wrong. It should be `this.set(10, -(this.#far + this.#near) * nf);` and `this.set(14, -(2 * this.#far * this.#near) * nf);`. See http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html#perspective

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks for the suggestion, and yup it was wrong, which is why I had depth disabled, but with the new suggestion I re-enabled depth, and set it to `gl.LEQUAL`, and it now works properly, but it still didnt fix the original issue, I will make sure to update the question.

Comment: I know whats causing the issue, as when I set near to anything but 0.0, it will mimic the results every where else, so I need to fix my calculations

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it was the perspective camera, I switched it over to mat4 orthographic camera, and (Finally) it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mat4 does not calculate their Perspective camera properly for my code to work with it, however, it does work correctly with the Orthographic camera, I worked it out, and converted it back to a Perspective camera.

```js
class Camera extends Mat4 {
    // ... Other code (See question)
    camReset() {
        var f = 1.0 / Math.tan(this.#fov / 2.0);
        var nf = 1.0 / (this.#near - this.#far);
        this.setMatrix([
            f / (width / height), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, f, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, (this.#far - this.#near) * nf, -1.0,
            0.0, 0.0, (this.#far + this.#near) * nf, 0.0
        ]); // -(this.#far + this.#near) * nf -> (this.#far - this.#near) * nf
    }
    // ... Other code (See question)
}
```